# Is there a way to set connection timeout of XML::LibXML->load_html( location => $url)

Tags: perl, libxml2, xml-libxml

I am on a very bad network. I would like to adjust the connnection timeout of the XML::LibXML Is there a way to do ? or I need to load html with LWP first ?

```
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_html( location => $url, recover => 2 );
```

Comment: The timeout parameter is not set by Perl, it is inside the C library [libxml2](http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-nanohttp.html). BTW it seems the C module is only able to get http (not https protocol). So I think you will need to use the Perl module [LWP::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) to fetch the html page first

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/bmharper/libxml2/blob/master/nanohttp.c#L164) is the reference to the source code where the timeout parameter is set.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would use [Mojo::UserAgent](https://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojo/UserAgent):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use  Mojo::UserAgent;
use XML::LibXML;

my $url = "https://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml";
my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
$ua->max_redirects(0)->connect_timeout(3)->request_timeout(5);

my $xml = $ua->get( $url )->result->body;
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( string => $xml );


print $doc->toString();
```